# Twitter Bootstrap - Do not want responsiveness

Tags: css

I'm redesigning my comics website, http://HittingTreesWithSticks.com, and have been having a lot of trouble with the responsiveness. That being said, I'd like to redo it without responsiveness.

So when I make the screen smaller, elements won't shrink, like http://theoatmeal.com/.

I've only included `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen"/>` in my header, and not the responsive file, yet it's still responsive. Why is that?

Also, do I need to change everything to  instead of ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your site unresponsive by doing the following:

- Remove all of the `@media` rules and styles within them at the bottom of bootstrap.css
- Remove `max-width: 100%;` from the `img {}` rule
- Make sure your HTML doesn't contain any class names with "-fluid"

Comment: Bootstrap allows you to customize your package before using it... don't they have an easier method than that to remove responsiveness?

Comment: The recent update to Bootstrap 2.3.0, includes a single stylesheet (to reduce the number of HTTP requests), as opposed to having the @media styles in a separate file like before. If you don't want/need them, you can go to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html and uncheck the boxes under Responsive download a copy without the responsive styles.

Comment: I did do that... I downloaded my css without the responsive styles but it's still responsive... is that due to the rows being "fluid"?

Comment: I just tried downloading a customized Bootstrap build and unchecked all of the Responsive styles. I opened the bootstrap.css in the zip and searched for @media and only found one, which was for print styles. I suggest trying it again or just delete them in the bottom of your stylesheet.

Comment: okay, do I have to remove media="screen" from my included style sheets?

Comment: Yes, remove it. bootstrap.css includes print styles. If you leave the media="screen", and someone goes to print a page on your website, it will print without any styles being applied.

Comment: But note that the page width will still change even if you will remove it.

Comment: @user1189382 Yes I'm noticing this... I want things to remain constant size... if you change your browser window while on facebook.com, everything stays where it should, it's just that you can't see some things... I want that. If I remove responsiveness, and shrink the browser window, things start to overlap... If I keep responsiveness, the images shrink which I don't want.

Comment: That's because of all of the @media styles in bootstrap.css. Remove the styles in my edited post above and that will keep things from changing when you resize your browser window.

Comment: Strange. Can you post your changes to your live site?

Comment: @htmled Okay I made changes to the live site

Comment: Just checked out your site, cleared cache and I'm still seeing the @media styles at the bottom of http://hittingtreeswithsticks.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24250/discussion-between-growler-and-htmled)